# How to "deploy" in kubernetes without any changes, just to get pods to cycle

Tags: kubernetes

#### What I am trying to do:

The app that runs in the Pod does some refreshing of its data files on start.
I need to restart the container each time I want to refresh the data.
(A refresh can take a few minutes, so I have a Probe checking for readiness.)

#### What I *think* is a solution:

I will run a [scheduled job](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/scheduled-jobs/) to do a *rolling-update* kind of deploy, which will take the old Pods out, one at a time and replace them, without downtime.

#### Where I'm stuck:

How do I trigger a deploy, if I haven't changed anything??

Also, I need to be able to do this from the scheduled job, obviously, so no manual editing..

Any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#updating-a-deployment):

> **Note:** a Deployment’s rollout is triggered if and only if the Deployment’s pod template (i.e. **`.spec.template`**) is changed, e.g. updating labels or container images of the template.

You can just use `kubectl patch` to update i.e. a label inside `.spec.template`.

Comment: So just a label like `timestamp=<unixtimestamp>`? I'll give that a try, thanks!

Comment: Yes. You can use this command: `kubectl patch deployment hello-world -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"date\":\"$(date +%s)\"}}}}}"`

Comment: Brilliant! I hope to get a chance to test this this week! :)

Comment: Ended up setting an annotation rather than a label. Other than that, your answer is perfect. :)

Answer (score 39):

As of kubectl 1.15, you can run:

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment <deploymentname>
```

What this does internally, is patch the deployment with a `kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt` annotation so the scheduler performs a rollout according to the deployment update strategy.

For previous versions of Kubernetes, you can simulate a similar thing:

```
 kubectl set env deployment --env="LAST_MANUAL_RESTART=$(date +%s)"  "deploymentname"
```

And even replace all in a single namespace:

```
 kubectl set env --all deployment --env="LAST_MANUAL_RESTART=$(date +%s)" --namespace=...
```