# How to rolling update deployment in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app:  test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name:  test
        image: xxx:latest 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: aaaa
```

I use the tag "latest". When I update the image,and the new image is still "latest". When I  "kubectl set image deployments/test test=xxx:latest",nothing happend. What should I do?

Comment: Are you pulling the image from your local docker images or from a repository? And can you try updating the image with some other version? Does it still not change anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "deploy" in kubernetes without any changes, just to get pods to cycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500377/how-to-deploy-in-kubernetes-without-any-changes-just-to-get-pods-to-cycle)

Answer (score 3):

a RollingUpdate is always triggered when the PodTemplateSpec under `template` is changed.

While using the `:latest` tag is not suggested it can still work when using `imagePullPolicy: Always` and a label which is changed with every image adjustment. Sth like this:

```
kubectl patch deployment test -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"date\"‌​:\"$(date +%s)\"}}}}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rolling update depends on docker image tags. If you're using the `latest` tag in your deployment, you need to cut a new image with a new version.

The deployment resource can't determine if the images has changed if you're always using the `latest` tag. As far as k8s is concerned, you're already *running* an image with the tag `latest`, so it doesn't have anything to do.

It's highly recommended not to use `latest` for deployments for this reason. You'll have a much easier time if you version your docker images correctly.